# How variable work inside while function in JavaScript?

Tags: while-loop

Question :- why it is need to introduce same dice function inside while function because if not introduced while function goes on till the infinity?

```
let dice = Math.trunc(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
while (dice !== 6) {
  console.log(`Dice value is ${dice}`);
  dice = Math.trunc(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
  if (dice === 6) console.log(`Here comes your value`);
}
```

Comment: Because `dice` never changes  otherwise.

Comment: Note that the singular of `dice` is `die`.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not set the value again then dice will never change and you will have the same random number as first defined in the program!